# How to make .iso of current installation using Respin?

Tags: 16.04, iso, custom-distributions

Can someone please walk me through the use of the [Respin tool](http://www.linuxrespin.org/) to make a live copy of my .iso that I can use on other machines? I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Furthermore, can I then use this .iso with something like Rufus to make a bootable USB?

The intention is for me to configure Ubuntu with certain software and then distribute it to others.

Comment: I use Systeback...if ur os contains too much software installed(4gb+) then it wont make any iso... instead it will create .sblive file which can be used to make bootable

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this software hasn't been updated in a year. Is it compatible with Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Yes..it is..else try other Pinguybuilder remastersys and many more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:sergiomejia666/respin 
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:sergiomejia666/xresprobe 
 sudo apt-get update 
 sudo apt-get install xresprobe respin isolinux
```

Guidelines :

```
 sudo respin backup (to make a livecd/dvd backup of your system)

 sudo respin backup custom.iso (to make a livecd/dvd backup and call the iso custom.iso).

 sudo respin clean (to clean up temporary files of respin) sudo respin dist (to make a distributable livecd/dvd of your system)

 sudo respin dist cdfs (to make a distributable livecd/dvd filesystem only)

 sudo respin dist iso custom.iso (to make a distributable iso named custom.iso but only if the cdfs is already present)
```

note: cdfs and iso options should only be used if you wish to modify something on the cd before the iso is created. An example of this would be to modify the isolinux portion of the livecd/dvd

Run :

```
 sudo respin dist cdfs

 sudo respin dist iso custom.iso
```

(Time consuming processes)

Iso file will be in :
`/home/respin/respin`! Depending on the softwares you have installed size will be larger!

Comment: For me (16.04.02) it still says `xresprobe has no installation candidate`

Comment: @Scz I don't know if respin ppa still has support.. Try other tools..there are plenty of others..i haven't used ubuntu since long time..there might be little change in instructions here as well..refer https://askubuntu.com/a/831803/593116