# How do i make a custom Kubuntu distro?

Tags: kubuntu, custom-distributions

I am trying to make a custom kubuntu 20.04 distro. Are there any good tools I can use?

Comment: Check Respin, which is a fork of Remastersys after it's end of development - see [Build my own Ubuntu ISO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829652/build-my-own-ubuntu-iso)

Comment: Depends upon the kinds of customization you want to make. Many folks have asked this question before - try the Search box at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first try to package your config changes and added dependencies into one or multiple .deb files.

once they are installable easily, you can think of how yo are going to distribute it.

the suggestions posted as comments to your questions sounded like good suggestions.

have fun