# How to modify Ubuntu sources and compile them into a disc image (ISO)?

Tags: compiling, source-code

I've googled for Ubuntu source code, got on their GitHub and unfortunately didn't find it. I'm looking for a source code that can be built/compiled as ISO and what are the requirements to do so.

This is a related question [Where can I find the source code of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167468/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-ubuntu?newreg=eecbb5e288434ade818ca2018ea54d9d), which is outdated now.

Why I want the source code? So that I can modify how the OS behaves in some way (like drag-n-drop in taskbar, customize the start menu etc.). Where can I find it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find the source code of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167468/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-ubuntu)   If you want the source code, you use `apt source` as per the link you provided to download it.. It downloads everything you need to modify/rebuild a package (*assuming you've already got the build tools installed*)  What's wrong with that approach?  Ubuntu ISOs however are built by launchpad, using packages that are pre-built (*earlier*) on launchpad.

Comment: @guiverc I'm running Windows 10 for development. So would it be feasible to use something like WSL for running that apt command?

Comment: Download from launchpad then?   (where the source for Ubuntu is built/compiled; & seeded to ISOs...) or packages.ubuntu.com.  eg. for `base-files` just looking at the packages.ubuntu.com will provide a download link, the same as you'll get from the `apt source` command, eg. https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/base-files  (look and you'll see the *Download Source Package*)

Comment: @guiverc You mentioned `base-files` as an example or is that package the actual OS source?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build my own Ubuntu ISO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829652/build-my-own-ubuntu-iso)

Comment: @24601 Is this mostly for generating ISO of the current system? I was wanting to edit the sources.

Comment: `base-files` was used as example only, you gave no product/release details (ie. no clue as to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server etc) thus I picked a rather key package that would exist in most (*if not all*), ie. the package that contains `/etc/os-release` or the OS textual details itself..  Ubuntu is built from packages; and thus all commands are built around those packages... even the *seed* files that control what's put on an ISO is mostly just a list of what packages are included

Comment: @guiverc But isn't it _`meta`_? I got the .deb as well, but does it work like a file? I checked the meta file, but it seems to have nothing related to the OS.

Comment: @guiverc I'm unable to open DEB with WinRAR (fails to open) or [Altap Salamander](https://www.altap.cz/salamander/features/deb-viewer-browser-extractor-windows/).